# How to add css to a remember_me in a flask app?

Tags: css, flask, jinja2

I have an html file in my flask app with

```
<div>{{ form.remember_me() }} {{ form.remember_me.label }}</div>
```

How can I add a css class to the remember me input itself, not to the div or span around. The goal is to redesign the checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a variable to the constructor like this:

```
{{ form.remember_me(class_='yourCustomClass') }}
```

Have you tried that? See the [quickstart guide on rendering fields here.](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/crash_course.html#rendering-fields)